# Upgrade PostgreSQL 9.1 to 9.3 and server no longer starts

Tags: postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.1

Technically, I didn't upgrade from 9.1 to 9.3, I built a new server with Ubuntu 14.04 and used my old 9.1 config files. PostgreSQL wouldn't start:

```
* Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
* The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output.
```

but the logs were empty.

Eventually, after comparing the stock 9.3 postgresql.conf file and my 9.1 file I figured out that, at some point, the config variable `unix_socket_directory` had been changed to `unix_socket_directories` (not that easy to pick up in a diff with many changes and comments after each line).

Posted because I couldn't find anything on the net about this (until after I already knew what the issue was).

Answer (score 1):

The config variable `unix_socket_directory` has been changed to `unix_socket_directories` in 9.3 - found in `postgresql.conf`